# Align Spans using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a webpage that displays the users' personal information, and I would like to align vertically the spans colored in red using Bootstrap.

The following is a screenshot of my form:

[image: Form]

and here is the HTML/CSS code I am using:

**HTML**

```
    <table class="table">            
    <tbody>            
    <div class="col-sm-6 test">
    <span class=""><strong >First Name: </strong></span>
    <span class="" style="color:red" >FirstName</span>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-6 test">
    <strong class="">Age: </strong>
    <span class="" style="color:red">Age</span>
    </div>  

    <div class="col-sm-6 test">
    <strong class="">Last Name: </strong>
    <span class="" style="color:red">LastName</span>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-sm-6 test" >
    <strong class="">Status: </strong>
    <span class="" style="color:red">Status</span>
    </div> 
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
    .test{
     border-top: 1px solid #e2eae9; vertical-align: middle; padding: 6px 8px;
    }
```

Comment: you can assign the col-xx-nn class to spans too, I believe, effectively aligning them.

Comment: They look like they are aligned vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using display table-row and display table-cell

Result: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/wgyxo8gv/7/)

```
.test{
 border-top: 1px solid #e2eae9; vertical-align: middle; padding: 6px 8px;
 display: table-row;

}
```

Result: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/wgyxo8gv/8/)

```
.test span{
  display: table-cell;
 }
```

Alternatively using bootstrap, you can make your test div as rows and your span as columns:

```
<div class="row test">
  <span class="col-sm-6"><strong >First Name: </strong></span>
  <span class="col-sm-6" style="color:red" >FirstName</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to stack the red text under the "labels" then you could do something like this:

```
<table class="table">            
    <tbody>            
    <div class="col-sm-6 test">
    <span class="col-sm-12"><strong >First Name: </strong></span>
    <span class="col-sm-12" style="color:red" >FirstName</span>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-6 test">
    <strong class="col-sm-12">Age: </strong>
    <span class="col-sm-12" style="color:red">Age</span>
    </div>  

    <div class="col-sm-6 test">
    <strong class="col-sm-12">Last Name: </strong>
    <span class="col-sm-12" style="color:red">LastName</span>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-sm-6 test" >
    <strong class="col-sm-12">Status: </strong>
    <span class="col-sm-12" style="color:red">Status</span>
    </div> 
    </tbody>
    </table>
```